# Adding 240v (NEMA 14-50) outlet right behind breaker panel

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, garage, 120-240v

The breaker panel is on the outside wall, right next to my garage. I want to install a 240v outlet right behind the panel, thru the wall.

If i open the panel, there are those round metal covers that can be popped to run cables into the box. 
Removing one shows the back of the interior drywall. ( since the breaker panel is recessed into the exterior wall)

Idea is simple. Add a 50amp breaker and just drill thru the drywall, run the appropriate cables (about 3 feet)  thru the hole and straight into one of these:

[Levinton 50 Amp, 125/250 Volt, NEMA 14-50R, 3P, 4W, Surface Mounted Receptacle](https://store.leviton.com/products/50-amp-125-250-volt-surface-mounting-receptacle-straight-blade-nema-14-50r-3p-4w-industrial-grade-grounding-side-wired-steel-strap-55050)

No wires would be exposed.

Would this be against code or any safety hazards that i need to be aware of?

Comment: What sort of cable would you be using?

Comment: You will need a bushing or cable clamp to exit the panel. If using NMB cable a clamp would be ok at the panel but the cable will need to be protected or behind the Sheetrock until the outlet.

Comment: Don't ever remove another of those "for exploration". You have to plug them, and that is hard to do when they are flush to the wall.  Now use the one you broke open.

Comment: @EdBeal The cable won't be existing the panel. The hole is *inside* the panel, flush to the wall. It doesn't need to exit the panel from the bottom nor top.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 6 gauge

Comment: Funny, I did not say the direction that it left the panel, left , right, top  ,or bottom, 3 try’s gave up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this it takes a simple bushing or clamp from the main panel. Since the cable is breaker protected as long as it is protected going out of the panel and into the new one it is code compliant. Well if you have a permit,